# sql - select slow of two table

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb

i have two table in my mariadb database, A and B :

my request is very slow 3 min 18.028 sec min with index.

sql request :

```
select Cid,time,step,cpu 
from A,B 
where B.CID2=A.CID 
group by CID;
```

first table A :

```
+------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| CID  | time                | step               | time_in_seconde |
+------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|    3 | 2017-07-27 06:35:52 | gege               |          13.229 |
|    4 | 2017-07-27 06:36:56 | titi               |          12.823 |
|    5 | 2017-07-27 06:55:04 | fefe               |          12.667 |
344039 rows in set (1.239 sec)
```

second table B ( :

```
+------+---------------------+-----------------+
| CID2  | time                | cpu             |
+------+---------------------+-----------------+
|    3 | 2017-07-27 06:35:52 |          0.01   |
|    4 | 2017-07-27 06:36:56 |          0.05   |
|    5 | 2017-07-27 06:55:04 |          0.03   |
51639 rows in set (0.181 sec)
```

request result:

```
+------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| CID  | time                | step               | time_in_seconde | cpu             |
+------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|    3 | 2017-07-27 06:35:52 | gege               |          13.229 |          0.01   |
|    4 | 2017-07-27 06:36:56 | titi               |          12.823 |          0.05   |
|    5 | 2017-07-27 06:55:04 | fefe               |          12.667 |          0.03   |
```

405 rows in set (3 min 18.028 sec)

mariadb config:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name                                          | Value                |
+--------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| aria_block_size                                        | 8192                 |
| aria_log_file_size                                     | 1073741824           |
| aria_max_sort_file_size                                | 9223372036853727232  |
| aria_pagecache_buffer_size                             | 134217728            |
| aria_pagecache_file_hash_size                          | 512                  |
| aria_sort_buffer_size                                  | 268434432            |
| binlog_cache_size                                      | 32768                |
| binlog_file_cache_size                                 | 16384                |
| binlog_stmt_cache_size                                 | 32768                |
| bulk_insert_buffer_size                                | 8388608              |
| delayed_queue_size                                     | 1000                 |
| histogram_size                                         | 0                    |
| host_cache_size                                        | 279                  |
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size                          | 134217728            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                                | 536870912            |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size                          | 25                   |
| innodb_ft_cache_size                                   | 8000000              |
| innodb_ft_max_token_size                               | 84                   |
| innodb_ft_min_token_size                               | 3                    |
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size                             | 640000000            |
| innodb_log_buffer_size                                 | 16777216             |
| innodb_log_file_size                                   | 50331648             |
| innodb_log_write_ahead_size                            | 8192                 |
| innodb_max_undo_log_size                               | 10485760             |
| innodb_online_alter_log_max_size                       | 134217728            |
| innodb_page_size                                       | 16384                |
| innodb_purge_batch_size                                | 300                  |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size                                | 1048576              |
| innodb_sync_array_size                                 | 1                    |
| join_buffer_size                                       | 134217728            |
| key_buffer_size                                        | 134217728            |
| key_cache_block_size                                   | 1024                 |
| key_cache_file_hash_size                               | 512                  |
| large_page_size                                        | 0                    |
| log_tc_size                                            | 24576                |
| max_binlog_cache_size                                  | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_binlog_size                                        | 1073741824           |
| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size                             | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_heap_table_size                                    | 16777216             |
| max_join_size                                          | 18446744073709551615 |
| max_long_data_size                                     | 16777216             |
| max_relay_log_size                                     | 1073741824           |
| metadata_locks_cache_size                              | 1024                 |
| mrr_buffer_size                                        | 262144               |
| myisam_block_size                                      | 1024                 |
| myisam_data_pointer_size                               | 6                    |
| myisam_max_sort_file_size                              | 9223372036853727232  |
| myisam_mmap_size                                       | 18446744073709551615 |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size                                | 134216704            |
| performance_schema_accounts_size                       | -1                   |
| performance_schema_digests_size                        | -1                   |
| performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size     | -1                   |
| performance_schema_events_stages_history_size          | -1                   |
| performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size | -1                   |
| performance_schema_events_statements_history_size      | -1                   |
| performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size      | -1                   |
| performance_schema_events_waits_history_size           | -1                   |
| performance_schema_hosts_size                          | -1                   |
| performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size          | -1                   |
| performance_schema_setup_actors_size                   | 100                  |
| performance_schema_setup_objects_size                  | 100                  |
| performance_schema_users_size                          | -1                   |
| preload_buffer_size                                    | 32768                |
| profiling_history_size                                 | 15                   |
| query_alloc_block_size                                 | 16384                |
| query_cache_size                                       | 0                    |
| query_prealloc_size                                    | 24576                |
| range_alloc_block_size                                 | 4096                 |
| read_buffer_size                                       | 131072               |
| read_rnd_buffer_size                                   | 262144               |
| rowid_merge_buff_size                                  | 8388608              |
| sort_buffer_size                                       | 2097152              |
| thread_cache_size                                      | 4                    |
| thread_pool_size                                       | 2                    |
| tmp_disk_table_size                                    | 18446744073709551615 |
| tmp_memory_table_size                                  | 16777216             |
| tmp_table_size                                         | 16777216             |
| transaction_alloc_block_size                           | 8192                 |
| transaction_prealloc_size                              | 4096                 |
| wsrep_max_ws_size                                      | 2147483647           |
+--------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

my config:

```
[root/]# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3788        1177         143          10        2467        2326
Swap:          1535         284        1251

processor : Intel Celeron_4x0 (Conroe/Merom Class Core 2)
```

my question is how to increase the speed of my request ?

Comment: Can you clarify if `CID` and `CID2` are primary keys? It would also be useful if you could post the execution plan of your query, that is, the result of `EXPLAIN SELECT CID ...` and even `ANALYZE SELECT CID ...`.

Comment: Why the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: @dfg ert Let's try a different approach - please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE cid; B) SHOW CREATE TABLE cid2; C) SHOW INDEX FROM cid; D) SHOW INDEX FROM cid2; E) EXPLAIN SELECT ....   Someone will try to assist - but only if you can provide information requested.

Answer (score 1):

"You can't tune your way out of a performance problem."  Indexes are the key.

Rewrite the query using the modern `JOIN..ON`:

```
select  Cid,time,step,cpu
    from  A
    JOIN  B  ON  B.CID2=A.CID
    group by  CID;
```

You need these indexes (or `PRIMARY KEYs`):

```
A:  (CID)
B:  (CID2)
```

Also, it is unclear why you need the `GROUP BY` at all.  In fact, it may be 'incorrect'.  Please elaborate.

To discuss further, please provide

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE -- for each table
EXPLAIN SELECT ...  -- for the query.
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your mariadb my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
REMOvE or lead with # 20190309 the following 3 items
join_buffer_size   of 128M
thread_cache_size   of 4
thread_pool_size   of 2
```

to allow defaults to work for you.
The join_buffer_size is per CONNECTION and not reasonable.
The other two are too restrictive for a reasonable sized server, see refman.